# How to reference a table by id

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I think the reason I can't find what I'm looking for is because I'm asking the wrong question. I'm new to codeigniter and mysql and I'm hoping someone can make sense of what I'm looking to do.

I have 2 tables:

```
Products:
id | name | price | store#

Store:
store# | address | phone | etc..
```

How can I query the products along with the store information at the same time? Say I grab product id #42 and it give me store #21. Is there a way to run 1 single query to pull all the data at the same time from both tables by simply searching for the product id?

I *think* `JOIN` is what I need to use but I'm a little confused. I'm hoping someone can clarify and point me in the right direction.

Comment: IT IS JOIN the keyword you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should do that. :)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN Store S
    ON S.StoreNumber = P.StoreNumber
WHERE P.id = 42
```

Comment: and then from there I can just echo $row->address; or anything else. thanks a lot I just didn't know how to ask..

Comment: or use a subquery like: SELECT *,(SELECT address FROM Store S WHERE S.StoreNumber = P.StoreNumber) FROM Products WHERE P.id=42

Comment: In the SQL JOIN example above, shouldn't the join be on S.StoreNumber = P.StoreNumber? Approach is right, but example appears incorrect and could cause further confusion.

Comment: @Josh Yes, yes it should. Thanks for pointing out my typo. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Products.id  , Store.StoreID
FROM Products, Store
where Products.id = 42
and Store.StoreID=21
```

Comment: You're cross joining the two tables and then limiting the result based on the one row out of tons that has the exact id combination you want. I don't usually use cross joins, but unless it auto optimizes that for you wouldn't that be much nastier on performance? Is there a reason you didn't use a join?

Comment: I am not good with databases but i don't understand the relation between productID and StoreID from his example. Please clarify the relation (Going to remove my answer,after your reply)

Comment: Well it looks like his `Products` table has a column on it called `store#` which is used to reference the store for that product on table `Store`. So if you select a record from `Products` (or multiple if you want) and then join to `Store` with on ON clause that says that the two tables have equal values for their `store#` columns, then you should have successfully linked the two. I am less familiar with MySql, but at least in Sql Server I believe it can do better optimizations if you're joining two tables where there is a foreign key between the two. It also limits the result set much more.